# Expanded list view not showing child object

Tags: android, arrays, listview, object, expandablelistview

So I have been able to show the group text, however when I expand im not sure how to get the child text.

```
 List<TeamObject> listDataDoc;
HashMap<TeamObject, List<DoctorObject>> listDataChildStaff;
```

Im passing listDataDoc and ListDataChildStaff into my adapter. In my main activity:

```
listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,  listDataDoc, listDataChildStaff);
```

How ever before this I am calling prepareListData();

```
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataDoc = new ArrayList<>();
    listDataChildStaff = new HashMap<>();

    ArrayList<TeamObject> all = new ArrayList<>();


    TeamObject adil = new TeamObject();
    adil.setStaffName("Adil Patel");
    adil.setStaffType(1);

    listDataDoc.add(adil);

    List<DoctorObject> adilGroup = new ArrayList<>();

    DoctorObject cindy = new DoctorObject("Cindy G");

    DoctorObject Bettina = new DoctorObject("Bettina");

    adilGroup.add(cindy);
    adilGroup.add(Bettina);

    listDataChildStaff.put(listDataDoc.get(0),adilGroup);
```

My Adapter then looks like this:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<TeamObject> _listDataHeader; // header titles
private HashMap<TeamObject, List<DoctorObject>> _listDataChild;

//Keep track of checks
//ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> check_states = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<TeamObject> listDataHeader, HashMap<TeamObject, List<DoctorObject>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;

}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);




    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_create_team_child, null);
    }

    final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxChild);

    chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                                if (isChecked == true){
                                                    //_listDataChild.get(childPosition)
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
    );

    //String test = String.valueOf(_listDataChild.containsKey("Adil"));

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.teamNameChild);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();

}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_create_team, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.teamName);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(_listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getStaffName());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Now when I run the app with that code I initially get this:

[image]

Great! However when I expand

I get the following error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.adilpatel.vitalengine, PID: 4493
                                                                     java.lang.ClassCastException: com.adilpatel.vitalengine.expand.DoctorObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                                                                         at com.adilpatel.vitalengine.Expand2.ExpandableListAdapter.getChildView(ExpandableListAdapter.java:54)
```

Line 54:

```
final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
```

I know this is wrong, but im not sure how to get the names from my child objects.

Comment: What is DoctorObject?\

Comment: @RobinDijkhof DoctorObject is an object that has name, specialty and a few more things. Basically How do I specify I want the .getName();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to cast `DoctorObject` to String and it's not possible. Instead of doing this create `getString()` method in your `DoctorObject` (which `getString` return name or title of `DoctroObject`) and do following:

```
DoctorObject model = (DoctorObject)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
String childText = model.getName();
```

Comment: I feel like we are close, when I did this and expanded the listview in the label it displays  "com....DoctorObject@2c36...." (I put ... because there is some extra junk)  And the one after that is the same but "@3fd..." Im assuming that this displaying the reference of the object as a string? Also DoctorObject has a few attributes such as name, specialty, location etc. So somehow it would have to be a .getName(); somewhere.

Comment: @Adilp yeah sure it return String. by getString() I mean return name or location.

Comment: I forgot to metion .getString(); would not work. I had to use toString(); for anything to show up. In the same way .getName(); would not work. The only options were toString, equals, hashCode etc.

Comment: @Adilp One thing to mention would you cast getChild to DoctorObject and then call getName? it definitely work I just do it today :D

Comment: Sorry can you explain that again?